# Run spark-submit in Scala code

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to execute below spark-submit script within code  and then get application ID that'll assign by YARN?

```
   bin/spark-submit 
--class com.my.application.XApp 
--master yarn-cluster --executor-memory 100m 
--num-executors 50 hdfs://name.node.server:8020/user/root/x-service-1.0.0-201512141101-assembly.jar 
1000
```

This is to enable user to start and stop the job via REST API.

I found,

> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html

```
 import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher;

       public class MyLauncher {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           Process spark = new SparkLauncher()
             .setAppResource("/my/app.jar")
             .setMainClass("my.spark.app.Main")
             .setMaster("local")
             .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "2g")
             .launch();
           spark.waitFor();
         }
       }
```

But I couldn't find a method to get application ID , also seems like app.jar has to be pre built before executing above code ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes your application jar does need to be prebuilt in those cases. It seems like something like the Spark Job Server or IBM Spark Kernel may be closer to what you want (although they reuse a Spark Context).

Comment: Does that mean it is not possible to have a single scala project that contains both Spark app and web service? Currently my build system bundles both service and app together. The service contains start , stop etc.

Comment: If use Process spark = new SparkLauncher()
    .setSparkHome("C:\\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6")
    .setAppResource("C:\\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\\lib\\spark-examples-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar")
    .setMainClass("org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi").setMaster("yarn-cluster").launch();

Is there way to obtain application_id in Yarn here ?

Answer (score 1):

SparkLauncher will only submit your built application. To get the application ID, you need to access the SparkContext within your application jar.

In your example, you could access the application ID in "/my/app.jar" (perhaps in "my.spark.app.Main") with:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
...
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())
sc.applicationId
```

This application ID will be the YARN application ID when the application is built and submitted in yarn-cluster mode.

[See the Spark Scala API docs.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext)

Support for accessing launched applications seems to be coming in Spark 1.6 ([SPARK-8673](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8673)). A Scala example derived from [this test suite](https://github.com/vanzin/spark/blob/97e5b386d8a591b3fb48fb3da6e94a4b3725f792/yarn/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/YarnClusterSuite.scala#L112) is below.

```
val handle = new SparkLauncher()
  ... // application configuration
  .setMaster("yarn-client")
  .startApplication()
try {
  handle.getAppId() should startWith ("application_")
  handle.stop()
} finally {
  handle.kill()
}
```

Handlers may be added to launched applications, but a listener API is exposed and is the recommended way for monitoring launched applications. [See this pull request for details](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/7052#issuecomment-134419771).

Comment: is it possible to invoke this script   bin/spark-submit 
--class com.my.application.XApp 
--master yarn-cluster --executor-memory 100m 
--num-executors 50 hdfs://name.node.server:8020/user/root/x-service-1.0.0-201512141101-assembly.jar 
1000 within code than using ethe SparkLauncher ?

Comment: @nish1013 yes, you could invoke the spark-submit in a shell script, then log the console output to capture the application ID, and then grep and awk for the application ID. For example `bin/spark-submit --class com.my.application.XApp ... > log.txt > 2>&1` and then `cat log.txt | grep 'Submitted application' $1 | awk '{print $NF}'`

Comment: Thank you . Is there way to grep applicationId without writing truly to a file ?

Answer (score 0):

Scala has SparkContext.applicationId, which is a unique identifier for the Spark application. Its format depends on the scheduler implementation. (i.e. in case of local spark app something like 'local-1433865536131' in case of YARN something like 'application_1433865536131_34483' )

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Comment: But how to get this application ID at the point of submitting the job ?